# If $q=1 \pmod{p}$, then every group of order $pq$ is either cyclic or isomorphic to $G_{p,q}$.

Tags: group-theory

I am studying group theory and encountered this problem.

If $q=1 \pmod{p}$, then every group of order $pq$ is either cyclic or isomorphic to $G_{p,q}$.

Here $G_{p,q}$ is defined as follows:
let $p, q$ be distinct primes with $q\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Let $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$ be the group of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ under multiplication.

\begin{equation*}
G_{pq}:=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_q) \mid a^{p}=1  \right\}
\end{equation*}

I don't know where to start. Can anyone help me solving this problem?

I edited the problem.

Comment: What is $G_{p,q}$?

Comment: @Randall It's a cyclic group $Z_{pq}$. Hungerford used this notation in his algebra book.

Comment: Then your conclusion is redundant:  $G$ is either cyclic or it's cyclic. That can't possibly be what he means.

Comment: My guess is that $G_{p,q}$ is the non-abelian group with generators $x, y$ satisfying order of $x$ is $p$, order of $y$ is $q$, and $yx=x^ty$ for some correctly chosen $t$.

Comment: @Randall I think you are right. Thanks.

Comment: When $p=2$ we get $q$ must be odd, and this boils down to the proof that a non-abelian group of order $2q$ must be dihedral.  Your problem is a generalization of this simpler fact.  You could start there to gain an understanding.

Comment: @Randall I added the definition of $G_{p, q}$.